# How to build the project successfully by maven?

Tags: java, maven

I found [this JavaFx project in GitHub](https://github.com/zonski/hello-javafx-maven-example).

I can run the `HelloJavaFxAndMavenApp` class which contains the `main` method and it works like a charm.

However, when I try to build the project using maven by the following command it does not work:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.zenjava.examples.hellojfxmaven.HelloJavaFxAndMavenApp
```

it complains by:

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Comment: Did you type `mvn` twice? Do you execute it in an IDE or a terminal? Remove the `mvn` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.zenjava.examples.hellojfxmaven.HelloJavaFxAndMavenApp`  seems to work just fine when I clone the project, build and run it.

From the error message it looks like you have a redundant `mvn` there (i.e., you've run `mvn mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.zenjava.examples.hellojfxmaven.HelloJavaFxAndMavenApp`. Remove the duplicate `mvn` and you should be fine.
One possible cause for this I could think of is if you're not running Maven from the command line, but from some tool/IDE. In this case, the tool itself already calls `mvn` and just expects the arguments (i.e., `exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.zenjava.examples.hellojfxmaven.HelloJavaFxAndMavenApp`).